# User watchlist design improvements with Laravel and Eloquent

Tags: database-design, laravel, eloquent

I'd like to implement a kind of watchlist per user on my application. The watchlist can hold different types of objects, each of those objects being a model in the database.

Here's a quick overview of the db schema I've yet implemented.

[image]

Most of the time I'll be needing to retrieve only specific items (like a Label, or an Artist) from that watchlist. This is how I got it working right now :

```
 // controller
 $watchedLabels = User::find(4)->labelsWatchlist();

 // user model
public function labelsWatchlist()
{
    $object_type = WatchlistObject::where('name', '=', 'label')->first();

    if ($watchlistObject) {
        return DB::table('users_watchlists')
                ->join('artists', 'users_watchlists.object_id', '=', 'artists.id')
                ->where('users_watchlists.user_id', '=', $this->id)
                ->where('users_watchlists.object_type_id', '=', $object_type->id)
                ->get();
    }
}
```

So as I said, this works perfectly... But for some reason that I can't explain, I don't really like that implementation, finding it a bit lame. I'd like to be able to get the same results in a, let's say "more fluid" manner, something like $user->watchlist->labels. But this isn't really possible with the current setup...

Any suggestions ?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a [polymorphic many-to-many relationship](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#many-to-many-polymorphic-relations):

```
// User model

// assuming Artist model is observable
public function artists()
{
   return $this->morphedByMany('Artist', 'object', 'users_watchlists');
}

// assuming Label model is observable as well
public function labels()
{
   return $this->morphedByMany('Label', 'object', 'users_watchlists');
}


// Artist model (teh same goes for any other observable model)
// assuming Artist model is observable
public function observers() // or users whatever suits you
{
   return $this->morphedToMany('User', 'object', 'users_watchlists');
}
```

Then simply call:

```
$user->labels; // collection of observed labels
$user->artists; // collection like above

$artist->observers; // collection of observing users
```

Comment: Can the attach/detach methods be used to manipulate entries in this scenario ?

Answer (score -2):

Take a look at relationships.

http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#relationships